# Xamarin Android popupwindow - crashes when inflated

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, clock, popupwindow, countdowntimer

I'm trying to create a pop up window that shows a clock (actually what i want is a countdown timer but one thing at a time!), the trouble is when i call the method to show the pop up window containing the clock, the app crashes.

The method is being called from an Activity not a fragment.

Here is the code:

```
public void clockPopup()
{

    LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)this.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);

    View myPopup = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.PopUpClockTimer, null);

    RunOnUiThread (() => {
        PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow (myPopup);
    });

        }
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```
[mono] Unhandled Exception:
[mono] Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type 'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown.
[mono]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Int32 resource, Android.Views.ViewGroup root) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at FrogPoint.Droid.MainActivity.clockPopup () [0x00020] in /Users/jakememery/Desktop/working Frogpoint/FrogPoint1.2_database/FindTheMonkey.Droid/MainActivity.cs:1548 
[mono]   at FrogPoint.Droid.MainActivity+<getBeaconData>c__async3.MoveNext () [0x00258] in /Users/jakememery/Desktop/working Frogpoint/FrogPoint1.2_database/FindTheMonkey.Droid/MainActivity.cs:1215 
[mono] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[mono]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at FrogPoint.Droid.MainActivity+<RangingBeaconsInRegion>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x0035d] in /Users/jakememery/Desktop/working Frogpoint/FrogPoint1.2_database/FindTheMonkey.Droid/MainActivity.cs:675 
[mono]   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
[mono] android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.AnalogClock
[mono]  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
[mono]  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
[mono]  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
[mono]  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
[mono]  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
[mono]  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
[mono]  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
[mono]  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
[mono]  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
[mono]  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
[mono]  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
[mono] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[mono]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
[mono]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[mono]  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
[mono]  ... 10 more
[mono] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
[mono]  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
[mono]  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
[mono]  at android.widget.AnalogClock.<init>(AnalogClock.java:57)
[mono]  at android.widget.AnalogClock.<init>(AnalogClock.java:67)
```

Here is the XML i'm trying to inflate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time sensitive offer" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/logo76" />
            <AnalogClock
                android:id="@+id/tabAnalogClock"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <DigitalClock
                android:id="@+id/tabDigitalClock"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dismiss"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dismiss" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anybody see where i'm going wrong here please?

Comment: Could you post the XML file you are trying to inflate? That would help allot!

Comment: Hi Chris, XML added, but as it happens it seems i've fixed that problem. I needed to call the method via runOnUiThread. No crash now. BUT, now what happens .... is absolutely nothing. The pop up window just doesn't show.
If i simply use "SetContentView (Resource.Layout.PopUpClockTimer);" it shows up fine, but obviously i'm not opening it as a pop up then. Any help on that would be great. Else i'll open a new thread. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems i simply needed to call the method like this:

```
RunOnUiThread (() => {
    clockPopup();
});
```

It doesn't crash now. But unfortunately neither does it display the pop up. But that's for another post.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing either:

```
popup.ShowAtLocation(...);
```

or

```
popup.ShowAsDropDown(...);
```

to actually display the popup window.